# Finished attic Framing

Tags: framing, attic

Can the drywall be installed all the way up to the ridge beam for a cathedral ceiling ? Or , should there be a collar tie that would double-up as a drywall backing ?    [image]

More info

- This is a Cape-Cod house built in the 1940s
- There is a continuous ridge beam spanning the entire length of the roof

Comment: How is is ventilated? **Is** it ventilated? Or is it just stuffed full of insulation with no roof ventilation?

Comment: @Ecnerwal, Baffles connect the edge vent (https://airvent.com/products/intake-vents/the-edge-vent) up to the ridge vent. The existing gable vent has been sealed off. No soffits around the roof since there is no overhang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were not collar ties when it was built, there's no need for them now - drywall to the peak if you like, since the venting is in order per comments.

Comment: Thank you for the input !

Comment: If there were collar ties earlier , can they be removed ? Or , would you recommend relocating them up near the ridge ?

Comment: Lacking the input of a licensed engineer (that people never seem to want to hire,) removing or relocating collar ties is a matter of **"You bet your house, and possibly your life or the lives of other who live there."** They are literally parts that hold your roof together.

Comment: The city inspector was okay with the build. Will hire a structural engineer for second opinion. Thank you.

Comment: Also , would you consider a retrofit application of LRU26Z as a possible alternative to Collar Ties ?https://www.strongtie.com/facemounthangersssl_solidsawnlumberconnector/lruz_hanger/p/lruz